# Input a list of list of floats and calculates the average of each column by iterating over the rows - python

Tags: python, list, loops, average

I have a list of list defined as 'list' containing two columns that I need to find the average by iterating over the rows. I would normally just use tuble, then sum the column and divide it with the length.

As I need to iterate I am pretty lost of what my approach is going to be? Can anyone point me in a direction

Comment: can you give sample input and expected output

Comment: Please use a list of dictionaries, e.g.  my_list = [ { 'name':'xyz', 'amount':100 }, { 'name':'abc', 'amount':200} ], then it looks more readable. You can average by: sum=0, for a in my_list: sum+=a['amount'], average=sum/len(my_list).

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if this is what is expected:

```py
>> data = [[1,2,3,1, 3], [4,5,6, 2, 1]]
>> print([sum(x)/len(x) for x in data])
>> [2.0, 3.6]
```

I am using Python3 here.
Also, you may avoid using keywords as variable names. Eg: `list`

Comment: When doing that on my dataset I get the message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. My dataset is defined of a txt file with 1000 lines